# What time function do I need to use with pthread_cond_timedwait?

Tags: c++, c, linux, synchronization, pthreads

The pthread_cond_timedwait function needs an absolute time in a time timespec structure.

What time function I'm suppose to use to obtain the absolute time. I saw a lot of example on the web and I found almost all time function used. (ftime, clock, gettimeofday, clock_gettime (with all possible CLOCK_...).

The pthread_cond_timedwait uses an absolute time. Will this waiting time affected by changing the time of the machine? Also if I get the absolute time with one of the time function, if the time of the machine change between the get and the addition of the delta time this will affect  the wait time? Is there a possibility to wait for an event with a relative time instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function to use is `clock_gettime()` with the clock id of the condition variable. This clock id is `CLOCK_REALTIME` by default but can be changed (such as to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`) by initializing the condition variable with a `pthread_condattr_t` on which `pthread_condattr_setclock()` has been called.

Using `time()` is not a good idea because this is not guaranteed to equal `tv_sec` of a `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)`. In some cases this can cause your program to busy-wait for `time()` to reach the second that was already reached by `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` a short while ago.

Comment: clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) is the way to get a time that is only increasing thus unaffected by changing the time of the system. Initializing the condition's attribute with pthread_condattr_setclock with CLOCK_MONOTONIC will make pthread_cond_timedwait wait with a relative time.

Answer (score 2):

I've used `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_REALTIME` myself. That should work satisfactorily and allow you to easily create an absolute timespec to timeout at.

Indeed there's a possibility that the machine time will advance while you do the wait setup. In general if you're waiting for a small enough amount of time that this would matter, you won't be getting as close to your requested wakeup time as you hope anyway. If your requested time has already passed by the time the timedwait call is made, it should just wake up immediately.

Solaris provides `pthread_cond_reltimedwait_np`, (np to mean non-portable) but I'm not aware of any such function on Linux. I'd suggest just waiting on the absolute time and, if needed, implementing a relative wait yourself.

Comment: It's a pity there isn't a `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`-based version.

Comment: Is the clock_gettime with CLOCK_REALTIME is "heavy" on the low level resources?

Comment: I don't believe so, but the best way to find out is to profile your specific application and if it shows that the `clock_gettime` is a significant problem only then try to optimize it.

Comment: According to your second paragraph, the software can behave differently close to the time change, this can be very dangerous. I think that pthread_cond_timedwait should be avoided.

Comment: @Vincent Indeed it can behave differently if for example someone resets the system clock. On the other hand if your software expects particular wakeup behavior/timing you will almost certainly see other problems due to assumptions at some point, even if you were able to use a relative wakeup time.

Comment: @caf You can call [`pthread_condattr_setclock`][^1] beforehand to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` with this function.

[^1]: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_condattr_setclock.html

Comment: @LnxPrgr3: Excellent! Thanks for letting me know about that.

Answer (score -1):

`timespec` is just a time in seconds (`time_t`) with additional nanoseconds. You can use relative time with `cond_relative_timed_wait`.

To obtain current system time in `time_t` form call `time(NULL);` from "time.h". More accurate would be to use

```
timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
```

which will return also nanoseconds.

Other functions can be used as well but the final result must be converted to number of seconds and number of nanoseconds.

Comment: I cannot find the definition of the function cond_relative_timed_wait(). Where it is defined?