# android does not have the method named pthread_condattr_setclock

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
Condition::Condition()
{
    #ifdef WIN32
    pthread_cond_init(&_condition, NULL);
    #else
    pthread_condattr_t attr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&attr);
    int r;
    if ((r = pthread_condattr_setclock(&attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC))) {
        THROW("set clock failed %d", r);
    }
    pthread_cond_init(&_condition, &attr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&attr);
    #endif
}
```

In ndkr8d,  donot have the method pthread_condattr_setclock。

This clock id is CLOCK_REALTIME by default but can be changed (such as to CLOCK_MONOTONIC) by initializing the condition variable with a pthread_condattr_t on which pthread_condattr_setclock() has been called. from [What time function do I need to use with pthread_cond_timedwait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006259/what-time-function-do-i-need-to-use-with-pthread-cond-timedwait/4238857#4238857)

My Question:I donot know wethter the default value of the condition variavle is CLOCK_MONOTONIC  or not CLOCK_REALTIME in Android. if CLOCK_MONOTONIC, I donot need to fix the problem.

Thanks, very much.